# Resizing Window leads to Zoom = 0 in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am working on  a small hobby project for the mobile phone.
Everything works fine except when I change the windows size (eg. by flipping the orientation of the smart phone).

As soon as I change the window size, the zoom resets to zero. Therefore the map shows the whole world.

I experimented with:

- `map.invalidateSize` : sets the Zoom immediately to zero
- `setZoom()`: doesnot seem to do anything
- `setminZoom()`:  inpredictable behavior

```js
id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onLocationFound, onLocationError,
        {enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 0, timeout: 999990000});


// Adding an event listener to locationfound event 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  

function onLocationFound(e) {
  var radius = e.coords.accuracy;
  istPosition = L.latLng(e.coords.latitude, e.coords.longitude);
  
  
// this is where the zoom becomes 0, when window is resized =>      
      map.fitBounds([istPosition, stationen[aktStation].startPosition]);
```

I searched the whole internet but could not find a solution.

Now, this cannot be an unusual requirement (changing the phone orientation while displaying a map). For example, in javascript there is "window.addEventListener("resize").

What is the recommended solution for Leaflet?

edit:

The problem occured when I hid the map with "pagemap.style.display = "none"; " and then executed map.fitBounds.

So now I am testing:

```js
if (pagemap.style.display != "none") {
        console.log("map is displayed")
        map.invalidateSize()
        map.fitBounds([istPosition, stationen[aktStation].startPosition]);
}
```

Comment: First you write "As soon as I change the window size  (eg. by flipping the orientation of the smart phone), the zoom resets to zero. ", but then you have function `onLocationFound(e)` where zoom to 0 happens and is source of your problem. These two does not go together. How is "flipping the orientation" connected to `onLocationFound(e)` ?

Comment: I am using navigator.geolocation.watchPosition to  continously trigger onLocationFound. (I added this in the code).

In debug mode, I can see the event continously triggering. As soon as I change the window size, the Zoom goes to 0 when map.fitBounds is executed.

Comment: Looks like I made some progress:

The problem occured when I hid the map with "pagemap.style.display = "none"; " and then executed map.fitBounds.

So now I am testing the solution that I added to the original post.
I  will provide additional information after the  testing

Answer (score 1):

The reasons was, that I first executed the  map.fitBounds and then displayed the map. (I had hidden the map with "display=none"). After changing the order, it works fine.
Apparently, mapfitBounds doesnot use the viewport,  but the size of the displayed map.